# what's the folder name for 1080p resource on android?

Tags: android

what's the folder name for 1080p resource on android?

I know mdpi support 320x480
hdpi support 480x800
xhdpi support 720p

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't that easy.  Mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi are all select based on screen density - basically the size of the pixels - not the number of pixels.  So, if your 1080p screen is very large, it could conceivably be an mdpi screen (yes, it happens). You have the alternative to use small, normal, large and xlarge as selectors but these aren't tightly defined. A 1080p screen should be xlarge but so should a 720p.

The document at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources is useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly worded question, but it seems like you are trying to support the new `1080 x 1920` phones coming out. The maximum pixel density that Android supports is `480 dpi`, which is called `xxhdpi`.

A phone (3"-5" diagonal) at `1080 x 1920` will fall into the `xxhdpi` density, like the [Samsung Galaxy S4](http://thenextweb.com/mobile/2013/03/15/samsung-galaxy-s-iv-announced/) at `441 dpi`. However, a tablet (7"+) at `1080 x 1920` **will not be xxhdpi**, so do not assume that density correlates to resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear about the Screen size, density pixels in android. I found tutorial [Tips for designers and developers Android](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/)